# Self installed fonts have wrong line height in UILabel

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel, uifont

I have installed two custom TTF fonts in my iPhone app (Cardo and New Athena Unicode). These are used in a multi-line UILabel, but for some reason the line height seems messed up: the lines have a lot of overlap.

What could cause this? Is it a bug in UILabel, or are the fonts not right? How can I edit or examine the contents of a TTF font file?

[image: The overlapping text in question]

Comment: Do you have a lipsum screenshot by any chance?

Comment: Added screenshot to question.

Comment: Have you tried different fonts? I had some problems with custom fonts too, but mine were because of "messed up" ttfs.

Comment: Don't forget that fonts are under license. Commercial fonts are prohibited to be installed with software regarding EULA and a lot of so called free fonts are free for personal use only

Comment: Do check the frame of the label. You probably need to adjust the frame size after changing the font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably the fonts. Please try changing only the font used in your app. Use an included iOS font. If the label displays correctly by just changing the fonts used, it is the font's fault. If not, post the code so we can track down the problem.

You can edit fonts with a number of programs such as Fontlab, Fontographer, TypeTool, FontForge, etc. As BobC mentions in a comment, there may be licensing issues.

Comment: The built-in iOS fonts work fine. So it sounds like the 3rd party fonts are not right. Thanks.